# am I using the wrong data type with predict.nnet() in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, xts, predict

My lack of understanding of R is causing me to grind to a halt in my work and seek your help.  I'm looking to build a neural network from some time series data and then build a prediction using separate data and the model returned by the trained neural network.

I created an `xts` containing the dependent variable `nxtCl` (a one-day forward closing stock price) and the independent variables (a set of corresponding prices and technical indicators).

I split the `xts` in two, one set being training data and the other set for testing/prediction, these are `miData.train` and `miData.test` respectively.  Subsequently I altered these two `xts` to be scaled data frames.

```
miData.train <- scale(as.data.frame(miData.train))
miDate.test <- scale(as.data.frame(miData.test))
```

Using the package `nnet` I am able to build a neural network from the training data:

```
nn <- nnet(nxtCl ~ .,data=miData.train,linout=T,size=10,decay=0.001,maxit=10000)
```

The `str()` output for this returned formula object is:

```
> str(nn)
List of 18
$ n            : num [1:3] 11 10 1
$ nunits       : int 23
$ nconn        : num [1:24] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ conn         : num [1:131] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
$ nsunits      : num 22
$ decay        : num 0.001
$ entropy      : logi FALSE
$ softmax      : logi FALSE
$ censored     : logi FALSE
$ value        : num 4.64
$ wts          : num [1:131] 2.73 -1.64 1.1 2.41 1.36 ...
$ convergence  : int 0
$ fitted.values: num [1:901, 1] -0.465 -0.501 -0.46 -0.431 -0.485 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:901] "2005-07-15" "2005-07-18" "2005-07-19" "2005-07-20" ...
.. ..$ : NULL
$ residuals    : num [1:901, 1] -0.0265 0.0487 0.0326 -0.0384 0.0632 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:901] "2005-07-15" "2005-07-18" "2005-07-19" "2005-07-20" ...
.. ..$ : NULL
$ call         : language nnet.formula(formula = nxtCl ~ ., data = miData.train, inout = T,      size = 10, decay = 0.001, maxit = 10000)
$ terms        : language nxtCl ~ Op + Hi + Lo + Cl + vul + smaten + smafif + smath + vol + rsi + dvi
$ coefnames    : chr [1:11] "Op" "Hi" "Lo" "Cl" ...
$ xlevels      : Named list()
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "nnet.formula" "nnet"
```

I then try to run the prediction function using this model `nn` and the data I kept separate `miData.test` using the following function:

```
preds <- predict(object=nn, miData.test)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in terms.default(object, data = data) : 
  no terms component nor attribute
```

Running `terms.default` on `miData.test` I see that my data frame does not have any attributes:

```
terms.default(miData.test)
  Error in terms.default(miData.test) : no terms component nor attribute
```

but is this why the prediction will not run?

`miData.test` has names that match the terms of `nn`:

```
> nn$terms
nxtCl ~ Op + Hi + Lo + Cl + vul + smaten + smafif + smath + vol + 
rsi + dvi

> names(miData.test)[1] "Op"     "Hi"     "Lo"     "Cl"     "vul"    "smaten" "smafif" "smath"  "vol"    "rsi"    "dvi"    "nxtCl"
```

And, in terms of structure, the data is exactly the same as that which was used to build `nn` in the first place.  I tried adding my own named attributes to `miData.test`, matching the terms of `nn` but that did not work.  The `str()` of `miData.test` returns:

```
> str(miData.test)
'data.frame':   400 obs. of  12 variables:
$ Op    : num  82.2 83.5 80.2 79.8 79.8 ...
$ Hi    : num  83.8 84.2 83 79.9 80.2 ...
$ Lo    : num  81 82.7 79.2 78.3 78 ...
$ Cl    : num  83.7 82.8 79.2 79 78.2 ...
$ vul   : num  4.69e+08 2.94e+08 4.79e+08 3.63e+08 3.17e+08 ...
$ smaten: num  84.1 84.1 83.8 83.3 82.8 ...
$ smafif: num  86.9 86.8 86.7 86.6 86.4 ...
$ smath : num  111 111 111 110 110 ...
$ vol   : num  0.335 0.341 0.401 0.402 0.382 ...
$ rsi   : num  45.7 43.6 36.6 36.3 34.7 ...
$ dvi   : num  0.00968 0.00306 -0.01575 -0.01189 -0.00623 ...
$ nxtCl : num  82.8 79.2 79 78.2 77.4 ...
```

Any help or insight in getting `predict()` to work in this instance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

---

Here's some reproducible code.  In putting this together, I have 'removed' the error.  Unfortunately, although it now works, I am none the wiser as to what was causing the problem before:

```
    require(quantstrat)
    require(PerformanceAnalytics)
    require(nnet)
    initDate <- "2004-09-30"
    endDate <- "2010-09-30"
    symbols <- c("SPY")
    getSymbols(symbols, from=initDate, to=endDate, index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))
    rsi <- RSI(Cl(SPY))
    smaTen <- SMA(Cl(SPY))
    smaFif <- SMA(Cl(SPY),n=50)
    nxtCl <- lag(Cl(SPY),-1)
    tmp <- SPY[,-5]
    tmp <- tmp[,-5]
    miData <- merge(tmp,rsi,smaTen,smaFif,nxtCl)
    names(miData) <- c("Op","Hi","Lo","Cl","rsi","smaTen","smaFif","nxtCl")
    miData <- miData[50:1512]
    scaled.miData <- scale(miData)
    miData.train <- as.data.frame(scaled.miData[1:1000])
    miData.test <- as.data.frame(scaled.miData[1001:1463])
    nn <- nnet(nxtCl ~ .,data=miData.train,linout=T,size=10,decay=0.001,maxit=10000)
    preds <- predict(object=nn, miData.test)
```

Comment: Without `miData.train` and `miData.test`, the problem is not reproducible: your code actually works on random data.

Comment: As an aside, don't run `scale` separately on your training and test datasets. This will result in each of them being scaled differently, so your predictions will be invalid. Combine them and run `scale` once, or save the scaling factors from your training data and apply them manually to your test data.

Comment: @HongOoi thank you for the tip wrt to scaling - I can see I hadn't really thought through the effect of re-scaling separately - thanks.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd I have edited to the above to add complete reproducible code.  In constructing the reproducible code the error I was encountering has gone, so I'm thinking the shut down & restart that I did on both myself and R last night has cleared out whatever sloppy code had previously caused the problem  Thanks for taking the time to look, anyway...

Comment: Check that `miData.train` and `miData.test` are equivalent in their data types via `str()`. Does it work if you do `predict(nn, newdata = miData.test)`?